# Polymorphism error in my model

Tags: ruby, polymorphism

I'm trying to make a polymorphic model for my reservations.

A reservation can be from a USER to a ROOM, or from a USER to a MENU.

Those are my classes and migrations.

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :reservations, as: reservable


class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :reservations, as: reservable

class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reservable, polymorphic: true
end
```

In my controller I'm trying to access my reservations thru:

```
def your_trips
    @trips = current_user.reservations
end
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
NameError in PagesController#home
undefined local variable or method `reservable' for #           <Class:0x000000054c8308> Did you mean? reset_table_name

Extracted source (around line #4):
Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/models/room.rb:4:in `<class:Room>'
app/models/room.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:3:in `home'
```

Does anyone have ideas why?

Comment: And what do you have in User class ??. Have you defined the relation reservation in the User class.?

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    
  
    
  
      has_many :rooms
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :authorizations
  has_many :documents  
  has_many :menus

Comment: Did you create actual database table and run migration?

Comment: class ChangingReservationToPolymorphic < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :reservations, :reservable_id, :integer
        add_column :reservations, :reservable_type, :string
    
        add_index :reservations, :reservable_id
        add_index :reservations, :reservable_type
      
      end
    end